# How to prevent instances of classes that are added to a List from being destroyed in an IEnumerator method?

Tags: c#, list, unity-game-engine, coroutine, ienumerator

I would be very grateful if you could help me to solve this issue.

Fields of OpponentItem class are supposed to be filled with the data from collectItems.

Our opponent's items will be listed in opponentList and its data is coming from incomingData. As I don't know when StartCoroutine ends collectData method sets progressBar and Update checks an element of opponentList.

Unfortunately OpponentItem objects instantiated in the method are gone therefore list is empty.

```
using UnityEngine;
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Reflection;

public class OpponentItem {

    public int item_id ;
    public string item_type;
    public string item_name;
    public int item_star; 
    public int item_bonus;

    public OpponentItem() : base(){

    }

}

public class TestBug : MonoBehaviour {

    public List<OpponentItem> opponentList;
    private float barValue;
    public bool isDone;

    public static string[] collectItems =  new string[5]{

        "item_id=12",
        "item_type=Weapon",
        "item_name=Sword",
        "item_star=2",
        "item_bonus=10",

    };

    public string[] incomingData;

    public float progressBar {

        get{ 

            return barValue;

        }
        set{

            barValue = value;
            isDone = true;
        }

    }

    void Start () {

        isDone = false;

        string joined = System.String.Join("|", collectItems);
        incomingData = new string[5];
        incomingData[0] = joined;
        incomingData[1] = joined;
        incomingData[2] = joined;
        incomingData[3] = joined;
        incomingData[4] = joined;

        opponentList = new List<OpponentItem>();

        StartCoroutine(collectData<OpponentItem>(opponentList, incomingData, collectItems));

    }

    void Update(){

        if (isDone){

            isDone = false;
            Debug.Log(opponentList[1].item_id);

        }
    }

    public IEnumerator collectData<T>(List<T> list, string[] tempArray, string[] queryArray) where T : new() {

        list =  new List<T>(tempArray.Length);

        for(int h = 0; h < tempArray.Length ; h++){

            list.Add(new T()); 

            string[] mybox = new string[queryArray.Length]; 
            mybox = tempArray[h].Split('|');

            for (int k = 0; k < queryArray.Length ; k++){

                string[] inbox = new string[2];
                inbox = mybox[k].Split('=');

                if (list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).FieldType.FullName == "System.Int32"){

                    list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).SetValue(list[h], Int32.Parse(inbox[1]));
                    Debug.Log(list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).GetValue(list[h]));

                }
                else if(list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).FieldType.FullName == "System.Single"){

                    list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).SetValue(list[h], Single.Parse(inbox[1]));
                    Debug.Log(list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).GetValue(list[h]));
                }
                else{

                    list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).SetValue(list[h], inbox[1]);
                    Debug.Log(list[h].GetType().GetField(inbox[0]).GetValue(list[h]));
                }

            }

        }

        yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.2f);
        progressBar += 0.5f; 
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is one problem.  Your list will always be empty, because by default parameters are passed by value (see this [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/0f66670z.aspx) link)

```
opponentList = new List<OpponentItem>();        
StartCoroutine(collectData<OpponentItem>(opponentList, incomingData, collectItems));
```

Once you assign `list = new List<T>(tempArray.Length)` you add your items to a new list reference, but not the one that is passed into collectData().

You have 2 options:

1) Clear the list instead of re-assign

```
 public IEnumerator collectData<T>(List<T> list, string[] tempArray, string[] queryArray) where T : new() {

    // list =  new List<T>(tempArray.Length); // ** problem
    list.Clear();  // ** try clearing the list instead

    for(int h = 0; h < tempArray.Length ; h++){
```

2) Pass the list by reference

```
 opponentList = new List<OpponentItem>();

 StartCoroutine(collectData<OpponentItem>(ref opponentList, incomingData, collectItems));

}

    public IEnumerator collectData<T>(ref List<T> list, string[] tempArray, string[] queryArray) where T : new() {

    list =  new List<T>(tempArray.Length);
```